# Run Nunit assertions from another class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, assertions

I have two classes that I made to build up an order. Basically the class to create the order works fine but I want to use assertions to validate the information that comes back. The first class builds up the order with generic values and gets it ready for me to apply the actual information in the other class. Here is a sample:

```
   public static OrderService Build(int Id, string password)
        {  
            var req = new OrderRequest
                {
                    Start = run,
                    Passsword = password,
                    ID = custId,
                };

            return req;
        }
```

Here is a sample of the class that would test the results with sample data I pass through:

```
    [TestCase(12565, "passWord")]
    public static void Case(int custId, string password)
    {
        var create = new Order();

        var req = Order.Build(custId, password);
        if (req == null) return;

        create.Resp = ws.Run(req) as OrderResponse;
        Assert.IsNotNull(create.Resp);
    }
```

These tests will run on their own and order the service whatever it is but my problem is being able to implement the assertions into the first class so I don't have to put that into the actual test case. I am using requests and responses from web services so it kind of gets sticky for me.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand -- what is your question? Not using the actual web service in the test or asserting `OrderService` instances? What is the `run` parameter? What's the actual _exercise_ or _act_ in this test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a mocking framework such as [moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) rather than actually calling a web service.

Calls to external technologies such as databases or web services would not be included in unit-tests. Unit-tests test business logic.

**Unit test**: tests the internal workings of a class - typically at the method level. It should be a stand-alone test which is not related to other resources or systems.

**Integration test**: tests the correct inter-operation of multiple subsystems.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but unfortunately I have to do it this way. We will incorporate moq frameworks in the future but for now I have to go about it this way.

Comment: You don't actually have to use a mock framework. You can implement the service interface with a "test" implementation. For example, the test web service implmentation could return a hard-coded string rather than the string returned from the real web service. By using interfaces, it will be easy to use a proper mocking framework later.

Comment: can you direct me to an example of this? I thought about using interfaces but it didn't work out for me,  but maybe I was implementing incorrectly.

Comment: I can't think of an example online, I'd have to search. However, if you put your code on here I'm sure many people can help.